# How would you hash a string in such a way that it can be un-hashed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, hash, compression

Suppose that you hash a string in python using a custom-made hash function named `sash()`.

`sash("hello world")` returns something like `2769834847158000631`.

What code (in python) would implement `sash()` function and a `unsash()` function such that `unsash(sash("hello world"))` returns `"hello world"`?

If you like, assume that the string contains ASCII characters only.

There are 128 ASCII characters.

Thus, each python string is like a natural number written in base 128.

Comment: How hashed does it have to be? base64 encoding the utf-8 encoded string would do it. Or base128 would make sense.

Comment: And what do you mean by "hash"? Hashes attempt to make an identifier that is unlikely to collide with other strings, is difficult to reproduce with a modified string, and is typically smaller (often a fixed size). This last part is what makes most hashes unreversable.

Comment: By definition, hashing is not reversible because of lost information. If it is reversible, it’s _encryption_.

Comment: What is your aim? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

A hash is fixed in size, whereas a string is not. Therefore there will be more more possible strings than hash values, making it impossible to reverse.

In your example, you have an 11-character string containing 77 bits. Your corresponding integer would fit in 64 bits (actually 62 bits, but I will take 64 bits as what you might have been imagining). If we consider *only* 11-character strings (obviously there are far more), we have 2<sup>77</sup> possible strings. Assuming a 64-bit hash, there are only 2<sup>64</sup> hash values. Each hash value would have, on average, 8192 strings that map to it. So given just the hash value, you would have no idea which of those 8192 strings to decode it to.

If you don't mind a hash of unbounded size, then sure, you can simply consider the string itself to be the hash. Then no decoding required. You can get a little fancier, since you are limiting the characters to 0..127, and pack seven bits for each character into a string of bytes, reducing the size by 1/8th. This is effectively the base-128 number you are referring to. You may be able to get it smaller with compression if your 0..127 characters do not have the same probability. Then *on average*, the string can be compressed, with some possible strings necessarily getting larger instead of smaller.